# Swift default argument and ignore argument in protocol method/function

Tags: ios, swift, arguments, protocols

How can I set a protocol's function so that it can receive an optional argument or even ignore it ?

I have this protocol :

```
protocol Game {
    func modeName(forRound: Int) -> ModeName
}
```

With these 2 **special** classes :

```
//Goal: Default forRound should be 0 if none provided
class OnlineGame : Game {
    func modeName(forRound: Int = 0) -> ModeName {
        //Some code
    }
}

//Goal: I don't care about the forRound value here
class OfflineGame : Game {
    func modeName(_ forRound: Int) -> ModeName {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the `protocol`, you are declaring "method", and [the first parameter of "method" has no external name by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID236). So here is the very **normal** case code:

```
class SomeGame: Game {
    func modeName(forRound: Int) -> ModeName {
        // ...
    }
}

let game: Game = SomeGame()
let modeName = game.modeName(1) // not `game.modeName(forRound: 1)`
```

In your `OnlineGame` case, [if the parameter has default value, it has external name automatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID170) even if it's the first parameter of the method. You can override that behavior with `_` as explicit **external name**:

```
class OnlineGame : Game {
    func modeName(_ forRound: Int = 0) -> ModeName {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

In your `OfflineGame` case, you can ignore the parameter with `_` as **internal name**:

```
class OfflineGame : Game {
    func modeName(_: Int) -> ModeName {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have a problem with `OnlineGame`, I can't call `game.modeName()` without a parameter if I set the function as you wrote in OnlineGame class : `func modeName(_ forRound: Int = 0) -> ModeName`

Comment: Nice. This worked for me. On my first try some time ago I obviously made some fault. Thanks!

Comment: @BabyAzerty How do you declare `game` variable? If that is `let game: Game = OnlineGame()`, You cannot directly call `.modeName()` on it, because the compiler doesn't know it's a instance of `OnlineGame` class.

Comment: Ok thanks :-) I guess I will modify the function to be `func modeName(forRound: Int?)` and assign a default value if nil.

Comment: @rintaro does this actually work? I see`Instance method 'modeName' has different argument labels from those required by protocol 'Game' ('modeName(forRound:)')` when trying this.